# Large File Upload to SharePoint Throwing Error (System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.)

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

I am trying to upload a large file to share point of size 2GB its throwing error 
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Can anyone let me know what i can modify to overcome this. Here is my code below
The code is written through SSIS script task.

---

WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.33 Safari/537.36");

```
            //Adding FedAuth cookies to Header O365
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SPToken))
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, SPToken);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code.

Comment: client.KeepAlive = false; ?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/faf9737d-5cb3-442b-bf9d-26341a204475/systemnetwebexception-the-request-was-aborted-the-request-was-canceled?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: Yeah tried with that keep alive and increasing timeout to max of 3600 in the variables still throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use webdav like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250097.aspx 
You can also manually upload from internet explorer -> library -> open in explorer -> upload to use webdav option.

Comment: Actually the requirement is to do via C# code inside SSIS script task.